# Double authentication with Web app & Web API needed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm stuck on how to solve following problem.
I'll start with describing what my app looks like in a general context.

**[ ASP MVC (Angular App) ]**

- Uses Owin cookie

**[ WEB API 2 ]**

- Uses Oauth Token Bearer

This scenario is happening:
User visits app and authenticates with a login form which lies in **ASP MVC app** and generates a cookie.

Now I've decided to use AngularJs to add a couple features which made me use $resources and **Web API 2**. However, those features are only available if user is authorized.

To the problem: Now I must use a token for each request to the **Web Api 2** to access different methods within controllers. This means I must login the user again but this time through AngularJs. Using /token route.

How would I do this?
Should I take the cookie, check credentials in it and send it as a authentication request?
Can I do something within the form authentication, in the same method, in the **Asp MVC app**?

Please help me, this gave me a lot of overhead. Walking from a simple app to this in 30min. Can't even get my head around all stuff in the authentication.

Regards!

Comment: Configure the WebAPI project to use Cookie and Token auth.  I am doing exactly the same thing, and as long as I decorate my WebAPI Controllers / Actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute, it behaves as expected (i.e. user logs in to the website and gets the cookie.  Angular app then makes requests to the API.)

Comment: @BrendanGreen
How would I do this?
Is there a way to tell the API to check Webapp for authentication, maybe by configuring it in web.config?

All I get after authenticating with cookie in Webapp and requesting API is "Unauthorized 401". Could you provide some code on your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My WebAPI supports both token and cookie auth.

During startup I register the authentication like this:

```
private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //Token 
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
    });

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"), 
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
            {
                // this is to ensure that a 401 response is sent if the
                // user is not authenticated, rather than redirecting to
                // a logon page.
            }
        },
        CookieDomain = ".example.com" //might not need to set this
    });
}
```

Comment: but when we call webapi through restclient from some other application. it redirects to login page and login page is obtained in response.

Comment: So you need the other application to get a bearer token first and then pass that along with the request.  Maybe you need to ask a new question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739936/web-app-and-web-api-authentication-in-same-application

asked it here